# Complex derivative vs. real derivative under a field isomorphism.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the isomorphic fields $\mathbb{C}$ and $\tilde{\mathbb{R}^2}$. With this I mean that $\tilde{\mathbb{R}^2}$ differs from $\mathbb{R}^2$ only in its multiplication rule: 
$$ (u,v),(u',v') \in \tilde{\mathbb{R}^2} \\
(u,v)\cdot_{\tilde{\mathbb{R}^2}}(u',v'):=(uu'-vv',uv'+vu').$$
Consider also the canonical field isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\tilde{\mathbb{R}^2}$:
$$ \varphi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\tilde{\mathbb{R}^2} \\
z\mapsto(Re(z),Im(z)).$$

> Given a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\supset D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, does $\varphi \circ f$ is differentiable? Why? Are there more properties needed from $\varphi$ to guarantee this? Should $\varphi$ be a diffeomorphism?

Comment: How can $\phi(f)$ be holomorphic in $\phi(D)$ a domain that's not $f$'s?

Comment: What I think you want to ask is if $\varphi\circ f\circ \varphi^{-1}$ is holomorphic in $\varphi(D)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, now I know better what my doubt was!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the geometric (clifford) algebra $\mathbb G^{(2,0)}$ with Cartesian basis vectors $e_1, e_2$.  There exists an isomorphism between the complex numbers $\mathbb C$ and the even subalgebra $\mathbb G^{(2,0)}_+$ under a map $\varphi$:

$$\varphi(x+iy) \mapsto x + y e_1 e_2$$

The geometric algebra already has the necessary product structure that you want.  Namely, $e_1 e_2 = -e_2 e_1$ and $e_1 e_1 = e_2 e_2 = 1$.  These are the properties of the geometric product.  Thus,

$$(x + y e_1 e_2)(u + v e_1 e_2) = xu + xv e_1 e_2 + uy e_1 e_2 - vy = (xu - yv) + (xv + yu) e_1 e_2$$

For this reason, $e_1 e_2$ is often suggestively denoted $i$ as well because under the geometric product, $(e_1 e_2)^2 = -1$.

The geometric algebra still admits a differential operator $\nabla = e_1 \partial_x + e_2 \partial_y$ as usually defined in traditional vector calculus.  Consider the action of this differential operator under the geometric product on a function $\nabla (\varphi \circ f)(x + iy)$.  If $f = g + ih$ for real scalar functions $g, h$, then the problem becomes

$$\begin{align*}\nabla \varphi[g(x,y) + i h(x,y) ] &= \nabla (g + h e_1 e_2) \\ &= e_1 \partial_x g + e_2 \partial_y g + e_2 \partial_x h - e_1 \partial_y h  \\ &= e_1 (\partial_x g - \partial_y h) + e_2 (\partial_y g + \partial_x h) \\ &= 0 \quad (\text{by C-R})\end{align*}$$

If this quantity is zero in both vector components, then you should see that it is plainly equivalent to satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann condition.  Such multivector fields in $\mathbb G^{(2,0)}$ (and other geometric algebras) are referred to as *monogenic functions*.

You should also note that the geometric derivative $\nabla$ does not keep its action closed in the even subalgebra of $G^{(2,0)}$.  The result, as written, is a *vector*.

For this reason, it's useful to dispense with restricting ourselves to the even subalgebra.  With the geometric product, there is no need or reason to do so.  Consider instead the map

$$\Phi: \mathbb C \to \mathbb G^{(2,0)}; \quad  \Phi(x + iy) = x e_1 - y e_2$$

If $f$ is a holomorphic function on some domain in $\mathbb C$, then the map $\Phi \circ f$ obeys

$$\begin{align*}\nabla (\Phi \circ f)(x + iy) &= \nabla [g e_1 - h e_2] \\ &= e_1 e_1 \partial_x g + e_2 e_1 \partial_y g - e_2 e_2 \partial_y h - e_1 e_2 \partial_x h \\ &= (\partial_x g - \partial_y h) + e_1 e_2 (\partial_y g + \partial_x h) \\ &= 0 \end{align*}$$

Again by the Cauchy-Riemann condition.  This minus sign introduced in $\Phi$ is well-known; converting electrodynamic or fluid dynamics problems to the complex plane requires it to get correct results.  Usually, however, we write $F = g e_1 - h e_2$ as a vector field in its own right, in which case the condition becomes

$$\nabla \cdot F = 0, \quad \nabla \wedge F = 0 \implies \nabla F = 0$$

which is a perfectly valid statement in geometric calculus, and this is what carries forth beyond 2d problems into 3d and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

$g = \varphi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is holomorphic in $\varphi(D)$ iff the definition-of-differentiable limit exists and is equal to $a\in\mathbb{C}$.

Let's investigate the limit.
$$
g'(z_0) := \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{g(z) - g(z_0)}{z-z_0}
$$

if it exists.  Well Since $\varphi^{-1}$ and $\varphi$ are homomorphisms we already have $g'(z_0) =$
$$
=\lim \frac{\varphi(f\circ\varphi^{-1}(z) - f\circ\varphi^{-1}(z_0))}{\varphi\circ\varphi^{-1}(z-z_0)}
\\ = \lim \varphi\left (\frac{f\circ\varphi^{-1}(z) - f\circ\varphi^{-1}(z_0)}{\varphi^{-1}(z) - \varphi^{-1}(z_0)}\right )
$$
I don't know how you'd prove that such a homomorphism $\varphi$ is continuous so let's say it must be continuous for this to work.  Well then $\lim \varphi(\dots) = \varphi(\lim \dots)$.   Let's have $\varphi^{-1}$ be continuous as well.  Then $z \rightarrow z_0$ iff $\varphi^{-1}(z) \rightarrow \varphi^{-1}(z_0)$.  So if $\varphi$ is an isomorphism that is also a homeomorphism, then $\varphi\circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is holomorphic.

Let's try to prove that this natural homomorphism is already continuous. $\forall z_0\in\mathbb{C}$, we want to show that as we get arbitrarily close to $z_0$, $\varphi(z)$ gets arbitrarily close to $\varphi(z_0)$.  Let $\epsilon \gt 0$, then does there exist an open ball $B = B_{\delta}(z_0)$ such that $\varphi(B) \subset B_{\epsilon}(\varphi(z_0))$?

I think you can show that somehow.  Let $\psi = \varphi^{-1}, \ \phi = \varphi$.  The equation defining an open ball in $\mathbb{C}$ is 
$$
|x - z_0| \lt \delta \\
\iff \\
(x - z_0)(x-z_0)^* \lt \delta^2 \\
\iff \\
(\psi(x') - \psi(z_0'))(\psi(x') - \psi(z_0'))^* \lt \delta^2 \\
\iff \\
\psi\left ( (x' - z_0')(x' - z_0')^* \right ) \lt \delta^2
$$
where the $x', z_0'$ are the image of $x,z_0$ under $\phi$.  We need a lemma that says that if $a \lt b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ are real, then $\phi(a) \lt \phi(b)$, i.e. it's order preserving on the reals.  Well if $a < b$, define $(a,0) \lt (b,0)$ as an ordering on the reals embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Putting it all together you could see that those natural isomorphisms are also *homeomorphisms* automatically if they're order preserving on the reals.